# In Mobx can a complex component have it's own store?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I have built a complex date management component that itself is made up of many smaller components nested a few layers deep.  The components at different levels need access to observables and actions that live in the root component.  I am dealing with this by passing what I need through props.  While this all works, the code would be much simpler and easier to follow if I could create a store in the root component, use provider, and then inject in the child components as needed.  Exactly like we do when creating a store for app wide use.

So to summarize...

I want each instance of my complex date component to create it's own instance of a store.  I want to then use provider and inject to pass this store instance to child components.

Before I proceed with this significant refactoring, I want to be sure that this approach will work and is sound. Is there an alternative approach that makes more sense.  Am I overlooking something?

Note: Although I know code samples are useful, I'm hoping that what I am describing is straight forward enough that they are not needed in this case.

Comment: Not sure how Provider works, but You can define multiple store and pass them through props across your components and it works. Looks it is possible through Provider either.(https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/114)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create stores for a component and use `Provider` and `inject` to pass them to child components. Actually that is what I do in my current project and it works well.

BTW, I think this is a big Pro of MobX compared to Redux. You do not need to keep all states in a single global store. You can create complicated components that work perfectly by themselves. It is object-oriented, which is the philosophy of React.